# What is wrong with this while loop?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

**Background**

I have created a script to:

- Read a list of ip's one at a time
- Copy a config file from local host to remote host
- Reboot remote host
- Close current ssh session

Contents of script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SSHPASS="OMITTED"
FILE_TO_COPY=/opt/someConfigFile.conf
TARGET_FOLDER=/opt/

echo "Reading ip list..."
cat $1 | while read ip
do
    echo "Copying file to $ip"
    sshpass -p $SSHPASS scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=3 $FILE_TO_COPY root@$ip:$TARGET_FOLDER
    echo "Sending reboot command to $ip"
    sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=3 'nohup reboot > /dev/null & exit'
    echo "Done for $ip"
done
echo "Done for all"
```

My script read entries from a text file where each entry are separated by a new line, something like:

```
192.168.XXX.XX1
192.168.XXX.XX2
192.168.XXX.XX3
192.168.XXX.XX4
```

When I run this script, `./ConfigSender.sh /host_list.txt` I can see the following ouput:

```
$> ./ConfigSender.sh /host_list.txt
Rading ip list...
Copying file to 192.168.XXX.XX1
Sending reboot command to 192.168.XXX.XX1
Done for 192.168.XXX.XX1
Done for all
$>
```

I expected to see the output for all entries in file. I suspected that commands inside `while` somehow broke the execution. So I edited my script to just prints the read ip value to output:

```
#...
echo "Reading ip list..."
cat $1 | while read ip
do
    echo "Copying file to $ip"
done
echo "Done for all"
```

This is the output:

```
$> ./ConfigSender.sh /host_list.txt
Rading ip list...
Copying file to 192.168.XXX.XX1
Copying file to 192.168.XXX.XX2
Copying file to 192.168.XXX.XX3
Copying file to 192.168.XXX.XX4
Done for all
$>
```

**Question**

It is clear that commands inside original `while` cause this behavior. What is wrong with while loop? What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Both @harrymc & @Kamil Maciorowski answers are solving my issue, many thanks. I decided to accept @harrymc's answer as it is more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sshpass` works by manipulating `stdin` to fool `ssh` into thinking it is getting the password from an interactive user. When you use a `... | while` style loop, the loop iterates for every line coming from `stdin`, which `sshpass` wipes out after the first call. That's why only the first line gets executed.

Several solutions are possible :

- Redirect for sshpass the standard input to `/dev/null`
- Wrap the whole loop body into braces to isolate stdin (`{}`)
- Assign to an array before the loop so that you are not using stdin
  `readarray a < file`
  `for ip in "${a[@]}"; do`
- Loop over a file descriptor other than stdin
  `while read -u 5 -r ip; do`
  `...`
  `done 5<file`

Answer (score 2):

I made some tests. I think your lines like

```
sshpass …
```

read `stdin`, they "eat" additional IPs provided by `cat`. You can investigate *why* it happens but it's enough to know that it *does* happen.

The solution is to give them some other input:

```
</dev/null sshpass …
```

Or you can rebuild your loop like this:

```
for ip in `cat $1`
do
 …
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will solve the problem, but you do not have provided the user and hostname in your ssh reboot command line.

`sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=3 root@$ip 'nohup reboot > /dev/null & exit'`